# Problems in starting a new ruby on rails project in windows command prompt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just installed ruby on rails using railsinstaller on windows 7. I can start rails using a command prompt. But when I start a new project, this is what I get:

```
C:\Sites>rails new first_cms -d mysql
  create
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/assets/images/.keep
  create  app/mailers/.keep
  create  app/models/.keep
  create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
  create  app/models/concerns/.keep
  create  bin
  create  bin/bundle
  create  bin/rails
  create  bin/rake
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/secrets.yml
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
  create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.keep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.keep
  create  log
  create  log/.keep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.keep
  create  test/controllers
  create  test/controllers/.keep
  create  test/mailers
  create  test/mailers/.keep
  create  test/models
  create  test/models/.keep
  create  test/helpers
  create  test/helpers/.keep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.keep
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
     run  bundle install
```

At this point, the command prompt just stops working. When I check the directory I notice that the new project files have already been created, though. My ruby and rails information are as follows

```
ruby:
bin:        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe
version:    ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]

rails:
bin:        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails.bat
version:    Rails 4.1.1
```

Why is the progress of the project stuck at 'run bundle install'? I'm totally new to rails so this is something confusing to me.

Comment: When you run 'bundle install' on its own what happens?

Comment: How long is it stuck for, e.g., how long did you wait?

Comment: @olive_tree C:\Sites>bundle install
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Could not locate Gemfile

Comment: @DaveNewton 10 minutes or so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be your connection as they said here, but it also can be something different. Sometimes, I got an error when I create a new rails projects exactly at the "run bundle install" moment. If the problem persists, you can try the way I did.

You can go to your project folder by typing: 
`cd first_cms`

And then you can install bundle manually:
`gem install bundle`

Then, you can run the bundle and the project creation will be finished:
`bundle install`

It worked for me! Hope it works for you

Comment: Thank you very much. Although I did have a hiccup in installing sql2 (the installer got stuck at that point)...a bit of googling suggested I use v 0.3.11 instead of 0.3.16. After that it worked like a gem (pun intended).

Answer (score 1):

How long have you been waiting? Bundler calls out to rubygems.org to install missing gems so it can sometimes take a minute on a freshly-created app.

Comment: I do have a very slow internet connection, so that might be a problem. I'll wait a little longer and see what happens and get back.

Comment: Sounds like it. Even with a fast connection, it can seem a little slow on the first run. (Rails itself has ~30 gems, if you haven't installed it already.)